# How does the sum of row in infinitesimal rate marix for Continous Time Markov Chain tend to zero?

Tags: markov-chains

i have a single question about the theory of infinitesimal rate or generator matix for CTMC. I have learned that the sum of row in infinitesimal rate or generator matrix have sum of zero. From many days, i have search many textbook and paper about it but i still dont know about the reason why does the sum of each row is tend to zero?

can anybody help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sum of each row is a probabilty vector. It must sum up to $1$

Comment: Incorrect for CTMC. You are talking about discrete MC.